# Tensorflow tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifer estimation accuracy does not align to DNNClassifier prediction accuracy

Tags: tensorflow

In general, what alignment should we expect between the accuracy achieved during estimation, and the accuracy achieved during prediction? Simply put, if we achieved an 85% accuracy during estimation, should we expect a similar result during prediction? There are a few other posts discussion prediction accuracy issues, but none appear to ask this question directly.

To be more specific, I am using a DNNClassifier to learn against 1000 rows of feature data, each with 53 characteristics (i.e. columns). This is then tested against 100 samples. The model is configured to classify against two labels: 0 and 1, and achieves the prediction accuracy below.

INFO:tensorflow:Saving evaluation summary for step 45300:
accuracy: 0.846154
accuracy/baseline_label_mean: 0.197802
accuracy/threshold_0.500000_mean: 0.846154
auc: 0.743912
global_step: 45300
labels/actual_label_mean: 0.197802
labels/prediction_mean: 0.283492
loss: 0.398202
precision/positive_threshold_0.500000_mean: 1.0
recall/positive_threshold_0.500000_mean: 0.222222

However, when 15 examples are then used during the prediction step, and where 50% should be classified with a label of 1, they are generally all returned as 0s. Occasionally, a single example will be correctly classified as a 1.

For example:
Predictions: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

My DNNClassifier is configured as follows:

```
m = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(model_dir=model_dir,
                                       feature_columns=deep_columns,
                                       hidden_units=[32, 16],
                                       activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                                       n_classes=2,
                                       optimizer=tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(
                                       learning_rate=0.1))
```

and the predict function is called as below:

```
y = m.predict(input_fn = lambda: input_fn(df_predict))
    predictions = list(itertools.islice(y, 15))
    print("Predictions: {}".format(str(predictions)))
    for i in predictions:
        print(i)
```

I have two questions.
(1) Am I correct to assume that there should be a direct correlation between estimation and prediction accuracy, and therefore that an 85% estimation accuracy should result in a similar prediction accuracy?

(2) Do the other results provided when training completes (i.e. "labels/prediction_mean: 0.283492") provide information that is relevant to the low level of prediction accuracy being achieved? I have not been able to find a definition of these result labels in the TensorFlow documentation, and my apologies if I have missed something.

Many thanks for any thoughts on this.